# Are ng-show and ng-hide exactly the same except for negated condition in AngularDart?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Are `ng-show` and `ng-hide` completely equivalent except that the interpretation of the condition is negated? E.g., is

```html
<div ng-show="someBoolExpr">...</div>
```

totally equivalent to

```html
<div ng-hide="!someBoolExpr">...</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. And now it is how it behaves in AngularJS.

This was diferent until recently.

Previously `ng-show` switched the `show` class but that doesn't make much sense.